# How do I connect to other computers via Host Name on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I have a docker container that is running on Windows currently and it is accessing database resources via the host name (e.g `Desktop1`, `Desktop2`, etc...). The docker container is using a bridge network that was created new for the purpose of the system.

What I notice on Windows is that I can ping or connect to those resources simply via the host name and I do not need to remember the IP address of the computer.

I also notice that this can also be done even if I don't have a DNS server running locally (I think?).

However, when I run the container on an Ubuntu host, I keep getting connection errors and timeouts.

I have tried to edit the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` to include the proper host name of the PC and the fixed wired IP I am using.

I have also tried a test database on the same Ubuntu system but I cannot connect to it via its host name. At best, I am able to connect via something like `Desktop1.local` but it only solves 1 issue. The other responses I receive from the other systems on the network return only the hostname (e.g. `http://Desktop2/api/...`, `ws://Desktop3/api/...`, etc...).

I was wondering if there is a configuration I am missing to have the same functionality as Windows? Do I need to change my code to handle this kind of situations or do I need to do something else like on the OS level?

My command for creating the docker container is along these lines:

```
docker create -p 172.16.0.1:50000:80/tcp --env MongoDatabaseSettings__ConnectionString="mongodb://desktop1:27017/?uuidRepresentation=standard" --env ConnectionStrings__MySQLConnection="server=desktop2;database=DB;user=user;password=password" --name container1 registry.gitlab.com/group/image:latest
```

Contents of my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
172.16.0.1   desktop1
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Docker internally provides its own DNS server and you shouldn't have to configure anything for it.  Are the `desktopN` systems you're referencing other containers or other systems on your network?

Comment: The ```desktopN``` systems refer to other systems on the network with a different subnet from the docker network but belong to the same subnet as the host system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's me, maybe will try to build the reverse proxy server.

#### Step. 1

> choose your server. (recommend `Nginx`)

#### Step. 2

> Forward traffic
> For example, if your ip of docker service is `192.168.1.2:8080`, then you can make `127.0.0.1:80` to forward to it. (or any port you want)
> Then you just need to access `127.0.0.1:80`, the server will forward the traffic to service of docker.

I dont know is that you actually want to do.

> oh, btw, if you still want to access via host name, just edit host file with root user. (make `127.0.0.1:80` a custom domain.

I dont know the reason of that why you can not setting the host file, but set `127.0.0.1` in host file is always working for me.